# Spark / Wiremock: guava version conflict

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, guava, wiremock

In a Spark application (v2.3.3), I want to use Wiremock from scala tests. I use following dependencies:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.3" % "provided"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.3" % "provided"
"com.github.tomakehurst" % "wiremock" % "2.25.1" % Test
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % Test
```

Doing so, I have the following error from a spark class:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1.apply(RDD.scala:962)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$toLocalIterator$1.apply(RDD.scala:958)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.toLocalIterator(RDD.scala:958)
```

Then if I exclude guava from Wiremock:

```
"com.github.tomakehurst" % "wiremock" % "2.25.1" % Test exclude("com.google", "guava")
```

I got the following using Wiremock:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.createStarted()Lcom/google/common/base/Stopwatch;
```

Because default guava version is 11.0.2 .

Using guava 18, which introduces the `createStarted` method, I still have the error `tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>`.

So the issue is that 2 librairies use incompatible versions of Guava. How to fix it? The solutions I found are related to uber-jar, but in my case this is only **in the Test scope**.

Comment: How to fix it? Ask the maintainers of the libraries you use to update their Guava version to the latest, and use the latest version of those libraries.

Comment: I use Spark on Google Platform, I have no choice of the available versions.

Comment: Wiremock 2.25.1 relies on Guava 20 (a 3 years old version), Spark 2.4.4 on Guava 14 (a 6.5 years old version) but they say 15 in the comments (a 6 years old version). Both need to be updated. Welcome to dependency hell! Since they are not used in the same scope, I would simply drop wiremock for now.

Comment: ... if I could then I would... but I need Wiremock

Answer (score 0):

Using the wiremock-standalone library solves the issue:

```
"com.github.tomakehurst" % "wiremock-standalone" % "2.25.1" % Test
```

I don't really understand why, if anyone has an explanation?

Comment: wiremock-standalone repackages as many of its dependencies as it can under a new wiremock package - so for instance it has `wiremock.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch` in its jar, and depends on that. A process known as shading. So there is no longer a clash, as far as the JVM is concerned `wiremock.com.google.common.base.Stopwatch` and `com.google.common.base.Stopwatch` are two totally different classes so they can coexist.